# Correct syntax for `if...elif` statements

Tags: bash

Quick question, assume the following `if`-statement

```
if dis'n'dat ; then
    some command here
else
    if dat'n'dis
        some other command
    fi
fi
```

could i change this using elif to following?

```
if dis'n'dat ; then
    some command
elif dat'n'dis ; then
    some other command
fi
```

despite beeing new to programming, the `if-else-fi`-statements i do understand but i never found an answer which explained elif in a way i would understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your re-write using elif is the same as your original code block using a nested 'if'.

Elif exists exactly so that you don't have to nest a new 'if' inside 'else'. I think that's probably why they call it 'elif'; it's a conglomeration of else and if.

Comment: Thanks a lot, would have tried this with a simple script but since i don't have a pc at my hands right now i couldn't check for myself. This bugged me beyond extend^^

Answer (score 2):

An `elif` idiom is very similar to the structure of a `case` statement.

Mainly: Only one of the matching cases is selected.

This:

```
if   test1; then
     code for test1 being true.
elif test2; then
     code for test2 being true.
elif test3; then
     code for test3 being true.
else
     code for all tests above being false.
fi
```

Will match only one of the matching `test`.

The difference with case is that in a case statement what is being tested are some patterns while in a `elif` statement several different tests may be used.